# How i can get value from field depending on language in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have ES index similar to the below mapping

```
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "note": {
      "type : text "
    }
```

in `note` field, I have many values in Arabic and many values in English and other Lang ..
how I can get the Arabic values only

Note: I have many million documents

Comment: If you have used the same field to index, all lang. content than its impossible to achieve, you need to index them in lang specific field with proper analyzer(for better search results). please refer to my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [multi-fields with analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) to implement the multi-lingual search

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "en": { 
            "type":     "text",
            "analyzer": "english"
          },
          "ar": { 
            "type":     "text",
            "analyzer": "arabic"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer medium blog on [multi-language search using Elasticsearch](https://towardsdatascience.com/designing-an-optimal-multi-language-search-engine-with-elasticsearch-3d2de1b9636d)

Comment: the mapping already built 
I want just search API , cause I have many million documents in this index 
and I don't want lose it

Comment: @MajdAlDeenm, yes, but unfortunately as mentioned in my comment in the question, its not possible, if you have already mixed all the language documents in the same field. you have no other option apart from reindex with proper mapping

Comment: @MajdAlDeen, you can use the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html to reindex and using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html you can do it with zero downtime

Comment: appreciate your kind help , i will try it .
i was hope if i found a way much easier :)

Comment: @MajdAlDeen, thanks for your update, I have implemented this and have done a lot of work in the mukti-lingual search and till now this is best I know which is supported in latest version, but please let me know if you find a better way :)